# Is "vector variable" a correct name?

Tags: calculus, functions

$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ is called a vector-valued function of a real variable. But what is
$g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$? Is it a vector-valued function of a real vector variable? Is vector variable the correct name?

And also, is $h:\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2$ a complex vector-valued function of a complex vector variable?

Comment: Point of pedantry: $\Bbb R$ can also easily be thought of as a vector space.

Comment: Probably more common to call these multivariable functions or functions of several real/complex variables

Comment: You could also say $g$ is a real vector-valued function of two real variables, and $h$ is a complex vector-valued function of two complex variables.

Comment: Most call functions of the form $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ "vector fields".

Comment: For a vector variable reference, see page 38 in Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg: https://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf. So, there are a variety of ways to describe these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $g$ is a vector-valued function. Interesting the domain and the range of $g$ are both vectors. So, it takes and gives vectors. The inputs and the outputs are both vectors.

The phrase "variable vector" is also not uncommon in literature as can be seen here: [variable vector](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22variable%20vector%22&rlz=1C1CHBD_en&sxsrf=ALeKk03wtLxgz6bCOFoxIHSrVT18JWoeow:1628414791688&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJi9LpjaHyAhUPfSsKHUafDnoQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1920&bih=937)

Regarding your last question, there seems nothing wrong. A more appropriate phrase would be "vector-valued rather than complex vector-valued".